# Remove same numbers in listview in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, random

Basically, my program generates random numbers either 1,2 or 3 and loops 9 times. I was wondering how I could remove repeated numbers from a `ListView`, so it would contain only 1 2 3.

Can this be done using IEnumerable.Except?

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Random rand = new Random();
     for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
     {
          lbl_Numb_1.Text = rand.Next(1, 4).ToString();
          ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(lbl_Numb_1.Text);

          listView3.Items.Add(lvi);
     }
}
```

[image]

Comment: @taji01: Is this using WinForms or WPF?

Comment: @Abhishek in WinForms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [HashSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/Bb359438(v=VS.110).aspx) to storage your numbers.

Or use LINQ and [distinct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/Bb348436(v=VS.110).aspx) to remove duplicated values like this:

```
var values = Enumerable.Range(0, 9).OrderBy(x => rng.Next(1, 4)).Distinct();
foreach (var value in values)
{
   ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(value);
   listView3.Items.Add(lvi);
}
```

If you want to use second variant, don't forget to add namespace:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: can i do this by using Enumerable.Except?

Comment: No. `Except` produces the set difference of two sequences. In your case you should use distinct.

Comment: how would i add this to my code it gives me an red error lines @Artem Kulikov

Comment: If you want to use LINQ you should add namespace: using System.Linq;

Comment: System.Linq is already in use. The problem is when I copied and pasted your code the data in the listview did not populate.  @Artem Kulikov

Comment: It was an advice how to use linq for your task. I updated the answer, now it adds values to your listView.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a check to see if it already exists in the list:

```
if (!listview3.Items.Contains(lvi))
    listview3.Items.Add(lvi);
```

Or you could just create a `Distinct` version of the same list:

```
List1 = Listview3.Distinct();
```

Comment: the listview still shows a list of 1 2 3 that is repeated . I just need the numbers 1 2 3 to show once in the listview.

Comment: That should do it. When you add each item (`lvi`) to the list, it will check if the list already is in the list, and if it isn't, it will add it.

Comment: @taji01 make sure you include the `!` - that checks if the item is *not* in the list

Answer (score 1):

You could check whether the listview items already contains the number

```
listView3.Items.Contains(lvi)
```

Or simply create a list and add the numbers, then `list.Distinct()` would return the distinct elements. Then you could assign the list to listview's `ItemsSource` property.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can just loop the values and select only the distinct ones with a `HashSet`

Answer (score 1):

Try this, this code will generate unique random numbers and add into `listView3`

```
int smallestNumber = 1;
int biggestNumber = 10;

//Determine the amount of random numbers
int amountOfRandomNumbers = 10;

//Create a list of numbers from which the routine
//shall choose the result numbers
var possibleNumbers = new List<int>();
for (int i = smallestNumber; i <= biggestNumber; i++)
    possibleNumbers.Add(i);

//Initialize a random number generator
Random rand = new Random();

//For-loop which picks each round a unique random number
for (int i = 0; i < amountOfRandomNumbers; i++)
{
     //Generate random number
     int randomNumber = rand.Next(1, possibleNumbers.Count) - 1;         
     ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(possibleNumbers[randomNumber].ToString());
     listView3.Items.Add(lvi);
     //Remove the chosen result number from possible numbers list
     possibleNumbers.RemoveAt(randomNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps man.

1. Create a method that can search for the values and returns you a ListViewItemCollection.
   [image]
2. Inside your "Remove duplicates" button.
   [image]

EDIT
- If you want this as Enumerable, you have to modify your create random numbers.

1. Create a separate accessible List and every time you add something in the ListView, it has to be added as well in the `List<object>`.

[image]

2. Your "Remove duplicates" button will not need to have loop from the ListView itself as you can use the `List<object>` with more access to LINQ features.
   [image]